# Scipy curve_fit for multiple variables and ODE

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, ode

My situation:
I have two ODE, one variable of ODE1 has to be calculated by ODE2 (only purpose of ODE2). Now I tried to prepare everything for the solve_ivp function of scipy:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
t0=0.5 #d
te=5 #d
t_step=1000
Bioc_start=10000
s_start=2
a=1.1 
b=100000
c=1   
def model(t, z, a, b, c):
        Ce, Sub = z 
        return [(a*(Sub/(Sub+c))*Ce),-1*(a/b)*(Sub/(Sub+c))*Ce]
    
    
#solve function
sol = solve_ivp(model, (t0, te), (Bioc_start,s_start), args=(a,b,c),t_eval=np.linspace(t0,te,t_step),method = 'BDF')

#plot
ax1  = plt.subplot()
in1  = ax1.plot(sol.t,sol.y[0], 'r--', label = 'Ce')
plt.ylabel('Ce $[unit]$')
plt.ylim(0,140000)
ax2  = ax1.twinx()
in2  = ax2.plot(sol.t,sol.y[1],'g:', label = 'Sub')
plt.ylabel('Sub $[unit]$')
plt.ylim(0.5,2.5)
lns  = in1+in2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc = 1)
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlim(0.5,5)
```

Now I have data for variable z (Ce, Sub) for the model and I would like to fit the model to the data. Variables a, b and c are constants. I tried following this guide: https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/18/Fitting-a-numerical-ODE-solution-to-data/#disqus_thread but i failed as I either dont understand how I could fit my model and variables into this type of fitting or it's not possible.

Data for Ce and Sub and plot of the real data:

```
Ce=[8000, 10000, 25000, 70000, 85000, 130000]
Sub=[2, 1.9, 1.7, 1.5, 1.1, 0.6]
ax1  = plt.subplot()
in1  = ax1.plot(Ce, 'r.', label = 'Ce')
plt.ylabel('Ce $[unit]$')
plt.ylim(0,140000)
ax2  = ax1.twinx()
in2  = ax2.plot(Sub,'g.', label = 'Sub')
plt.ylabel('Sub $[unit]$')
plt.ylim(0.5,2.5)
lns  = in1+in2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc = 1)
plt.title('Title')
plt.xlim(0.5,5)
```

Sorry for the lengthy post, let me know if additional information is needed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: Also, what are ODE1 and ODE2? Is `Ce` ODE1 and `Sub` ODE2 ? Do you only want to fit ODE1 to the data? (because you wrote that the only purpose of ODE2 is to calculate ODE1). What are the times for your datapoints? According to your plots, the data is for times 0,1,2,3,4,5. But then, you set plt.xlim(0.5,5) and integrate the ode with solve_ivp from time 0.5 to time 5, so it's confusing.